# Is it necessary to create migrations for all contexts that share tables (if migrations are enabled)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Please see the code below, which I borrowed from an online tutorial:

```
public class OrderReadContext: DbContext
    {
      public OrderReadContext() : base("name=GeekStuffSales") {

      }
      public DbSet<SalesOrder> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
      modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Order");
   }
  }
  public class OrderSystemContextConfig : DbConfiguration
  {
    public OrderSystemContextConfig() {
      SetDatabaseInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<OrderReadContext>());
    }

  }
```

and:

```
public class OrderWriteContext : DbContext
  {
    public OrderWriteContext() : base("name=GeekStuffSales")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<SalesOrder> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Order");
      modelBuilder.Entity<SalesOrder>().Ignore(s => s.LineItems);
    }
  }

  public class OrderSystemContextConfig : DbConfiguration
  {
    public OrderSystemContextConfig()
    {
      SetDatabaseInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<OrderWriteContext>());
    }
  }
```

If I just run the program, then I am understandably prompted with an error because Entity Framework tries to create the Sales Order table twice.  The following command (run inside Nuget Package Manager Console) resolves the issue:

```
  enable-migrations -ContextTypeName OrderWriteContext
        Add-Migration -configuration MyApp.Context.Configuration Initial
```

This creates a migration for the WriteContext only.  Does the ReadContext now require a migration?

**Question**

The way I understand migrations is as follows.  If you enable migrations, then you override the default - you do this if you want to set a default value or set a foreign key.  What happens if you create migrations for one context and not the other?